# Python: how can I add only a second y axis on the RHS with custom ticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes, imshow

I have a plot that I don't want to touch.
I only want to add a second y-axis on the right hand side, with its own unique custom tick mark values. I don't want to alter the plot at all.

The plot uses imshow:

```
plt.imshow(image)
```

and ny is the maximum number of points in the y axis

I want to add a second y axis that looks like this:

```
ax_ft = plt.twinx()
custom_yticks = [0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000]
ax_ft.yticks([0,ny/6,2*ny/6,3*ny/6,4*ny/6,5*ny/6,ny], custom_yticks) 
ax_ft.set_ylabel("Height [feet]", fontsize=18)
```

But it returns the error: "Axes object has no attribute 'yticks.'
So how do i just add a y axis on the RHS with those 7 tick mark values? I thought the twinx() would make ax_ft work like plt, and I could create custom axes?

Comment: Did you mean `ax_ft.yaxis.yticks`?

Comment: That results in AttributeError: 'YAxis' object has no attribute 'yticks'

Comment: How about `ax_ft.set_yticks`

Comment: That at least recognized the command!
But now there is an error: set_ticks() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.
This is odd because I am only sending it two arguments in the ( ) ??

Comment: Hang on a sec. I actually have wifi now, so I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: You can use secondary_yaxis https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some setup code for a MCVE:

```
img = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(100, 150))
ny = img.shape[0]

custom_labels = [0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000]
custom_locs = np.linspace(0, ny - 1, 7)
```

An alternative would be to define `custom_locs` as `np.linspace(0, ny, 7) - 0.5` if you wanted to go between image edges instead of pixel centers.

There are a couple of ways to approach this. The first is to try to use pyplot:

```
plt.imshow(img)
plt.twinx()
plt.yticks(custom_locs, custom_labels) 
plt.ylabel("Height [feet]", fontsize=18)
```

[image]

Notice that the limits of the axes are not tied together, so the plot is not doing what you actually want. The trick is to use [`Axes.secondary_yaxis`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_yaxis.html). At that point, you are using the object-oriented API, so I recommend starting with it from the very beginning:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
ax.imshow(img)
ax1 = ax.secondary_yaxis('right')
ax1.set_yticks(custom_locs)
ax1.set_yticklabels(custom_labels)
ax1.set_ylabel("Height [feet]", fontsize=18)
```

[image]

Note that the explicit answer to your attempts is given in the **Notes** section of the docs for ``.

> Calling this function with no arguments (e.g. `yticks()`) is the pyplot equivalent of calling [`get_yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yticks) and [`get_yticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yticklabels) on the current axes. Calling this function with arguments is the pyplot equivalent of calling [`set_yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks) and [`set_yticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels) on the current axes.

If you wanted the axis to ascend in the opposite direction from the primary axis, you could do one of two things. You could change the locations and labels, or you could use the `functions` argument to `secondary_yaxis`:

```
ax1 = ax.secondary_yaxis('right', functions=(lambda x: len(img) - x - 1, lambda x: len(img) - x - 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. The only issue is secondary_yaxis() doesn't work; it insists that it requires two inputs.
In my version of python (3.4.2), Definition : secondary_yaxis(self, location, *, functions=None, **kwargs). 
What do I enter for "self"? All the documentation I can find on secondary_yaxis doesn't describe "self".

Thanks so much

Comment: @tgbnez. `self` is fine, that's just the object you call the method on. I accidentally pasted an older attempt, missing `'right'`. Thanks for the catch. Fixed now.