# Linking dual axes after imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I am displaying an image using `imshow`, and trying to show a second set of y-ticks. For example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
ax.imshow(img)
ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax1)
ax1.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
```

[image]

Adding `ax.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax1)` appears to do nothing. The axes remain unlinked, and doing something like resizing the figure makes it even worse. Swapping `ax` and `ax1` in the `join` (`ax1.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax)`) raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/madphysicist/.venv/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt.py", line 477, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "/home/madphysicist/.venv/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 436, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/home/madphysicist/.venv/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 73, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/madphysicist/.venv/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "/home/madphysicist/.venv/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2823, in draw
    artists = self._get_draw_artists(renderer)
  File "/home/madphysicist/.venv/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 238, in _get_draw_artists
    ax.apply_aspect()
  File "/home/madphysicist/.venv/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1949, in apply_aspect
    raise RuntimeError("adjustable='datalim' is not allowed when both "
RuntimeError: adjustable='datalim' is not allowed when both axes are shared
```

How do I link the primary and secondary y-axes so that they behave as if I created them on subplots with `sharey=True`?

Inspired by [Python: how can I add only a second y axis on the RHS with custom ticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72409207/2988730)

Comment: twinx and sharey are not meant to be used together.  What are you actually trying to do?  Label both sides the same?  Have a secondary_yaxis? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html

Comment: Actually, why are you asking this here, versus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72409207/python-how-can-i-add-only-a-second-y-axis-on-the-rhs-with-custom-ticks

Comment: @JodyKlymak, Thanks. Secondary y-axis is *exactly* what I'm looking for. I guess I've been out of touch with matplotlib longer than I thought.

Comment: @JodyKlymak. Would you care to post an answer for me to accept?